# O que torna este programa em C inutilizado quando compilado em diferentes versões do GCC ou Clang?

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, gcc, malloc

Este programa em linguagem C é compilado em todas as versões do GCC sem nenhuma mensagem de erro, mas especificamente no GCC 6.3 e 8.3, o executável produz resultados totalmente incoerentes. No GCC 8.1 e 10.2 (os que eu uso na minha máquina) ele funciona perfeitamente. Qual pode ser a explicação?

```
/*
    Crie uma função do zero para determinar se uma string é palíndromo ou não
    (ignoring case and blank spaces). A utilização da biblioteca <string.h> não 
    é permitida.
*/

/*libraries*/
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
/*libraries*/

/*Fixed string max size*/
#define SIZE 100
/*Fixed string max size*/

/*strlen from scratch*/
size_t strlength(char *str) {
    size_t size = 0;
    while (str[++size] != '\0');
    return size;
}
/*strlen from scratch*/

/*Take off '\n' from fgets input*/
void takeOffNewLine(char *str) {
    str[strlength(str) - 1] = ('\0');
}
/*Take off '\n' from fgets input*/

/*strcpy from scratch*/
void strcopy(char *strDest, char *strSource) {
    size_t sourceSize = strlength(strSource);

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= sourceSize; i++) {
        strDest[i] = strSource[i];
    }
}
/*strcpy from scratch*/

/*Take off ' ' whitespaces from a string*/
void takeOffBlankChars(char *str) {
    size_t size = strlength(str);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            for (size_t j = i; j <= size; j++) {
                str[j] = str[j + 1]; 
            }
            i--; 
            /*
             * O decremento do iterador "i" 
             * mantém o array de caracteres na 
             * mesma posição onde o caractere 
             * em branco foi encontrado, com o 
             * intuito de checar se há outro 
             * whitespace em "str[i + 1]", que 
             * foi reposicionado para "str[i]".
             */  
        }
    }
}
/*Take off ' ' whitespaces from a string*/

/*entire string to lowercase*/
void strToLower(char *str) {
    size_t size = strlength(str);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
    str[size] = '\0';
}
/*entire string to lowercase*/

/*invert string*/
void invertStr(char *strSource, char *strInverted) {
    size_t size = strlength(strSource);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        strInverted[i] = strSource[size - i - 1];
    }
    strInverted[size] = ('\0');
}
/*invert string*/

/*check if they're palindromes*/
bool strccmp (char *str1, char *str2) {
    size_t sizeStr1 = strlength(str1);
    size_t sizeStr2 = strlength(str2);

    if(sizeStr1 != sizeStr2) {
        return false;
    }

    size_t size = sizeStr1;

    char *str1LwrCase = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    char *str2LwrCase = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    if (str1LwrCase == 0 || str2LwrCase == 0)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation error in <<strccmp()>>\n");
        return false;
    }
    
    strcopy(str1LwrCase, str1);
    strcopy(str2LwrCase, str2);

    takeOffBlankChars(str1LwrCase);
    takeOffBlankChars(str2LwrCase);

    strToLower(str1LwrCase);
    strToLower(str2LwrCase);

    bool isEqual = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; str1LwrCase[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(str1LwrCase[i] != str2LwrCase[i]) {
            isEqual = false;
            free(str1LwrCase);
            free(str2LwrCase);
            return isEqual;
        }
    }
    free(str1LwrCase);
    free(str2LwrCase);
    return isEqual;
}
/*check if they're palindromes*/

int main(void) {
    char s1[SIZE] = {'\0'};
    char s2[SIZE] = {'\0'};

    fgets(s1, SIZE, stdin);
    takeOffNewLine(s1);
    
    invertStr(s1, s2);

    if (strccmp(s1, s2)) {
        printf("It's a palindrome.\n");
    } 
    else {
        printf("It's not a palindrome.\n");
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**String input (que É um palídromo) testado por mim**: L I V R E do poder vil

**Resultado incorreto em**:

- ideone (GCC 8.3)
- codechef (GCC 6.3)

**Resultado correto em**:

- onlinegdb
- programiz
- tutorialspoint
- repl.it (Clang 7.0)
- jdoodle (GCC 5.3, 7.2, 8.1 e 9.1)
- Na minha máquina Windows 10 com MinGW64 e GCC 10.2, e no WSL com GCC (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Comment: Não é a causa do problema mas sua função `strlength` dá um resultado errado para uma string vazia. Você está presumindo que a função `fgets` **sempre** acrescentará um '\n' como último caractere da string lida, o que pode não ser verdade. Aqui https://ideone.com/fIfGt1 funcionou como o esperado (gcc 8.3).

Comment: Você matou a charada. O problema está na forma com que a string é lida, não tem nada a ver com o compilador. Somente quando o input é dado através de linha de comando o fgets captura o `\n` / _enter_ . E obrigado pela observação da `strlength()` . Vou checar a existência ou não do `newline` na função `takeOffNewLine()`